# Precompiling assets locally broke my app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, precompile

I am a newbie programmer following the Michael Hartl tutorial.

I was about to finish chapter 9, which adds the functionality to view all users at the site and delete individual ones with an admin functionality.

All specs were passing and everything working as expected, locally. However, when I tested the site at Heroku the index of the users looked different from the local index.

I tried to precompile assets before pushing to Heroku, which fixed to problem. However, now the functionality to delete users didn't work. Instead of deleting the user, I was forwarded to that user. The same happened to the local version. Furthermore, I noticed that clicking the sign-out link returned an error:

```
No route matches [GET] "/signout"
```

All my specs are still passing which only makes it more of a mystery to me! I suspect it's a problem with how assets are compiled, but as a rails newbie, it feels like looking for the needle in a haystack so any help is welcome.

routes.rb

```
Hooter::Application.routes.draw do

  resources :users
  resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]

  root to: 'static_pages#home'
  match '/help', to: 'static_pages#help'
  match '/about', to: 'static_pages#about'
  match '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact'
  match '/signup', to: 'users#new'
  match '/signin', to: 'sessions#new'
  match '/signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', via: :delete
```

user_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :signed_in_user, only: [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_filter :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update]
  before_filter :admin_user, only: :destroy

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
      @user = User.new(params[:user])
      if @user.save
        sign_in @user
        flash[:success] = "Welcome to the hooter App!"
        redirect_to @user
      else
        render 'new'
      end
  end

  def index
    @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
      sign_in(@user)
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    User.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:success] = "User destroyed"
    redirect_to users_url
  end

  private

      def signed_in_user
        unless signed_in?
          store_location
          redirect_to signin_url, notice: "Please sign in."
        end
      end

      def correct_user
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
        redirect_to(root_path) unless current_user?(@user)
      end

      def admin_user
        redirect_to(root_path) unless current_user.admin?
      end
end
```

_header.html.erb

```
<header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
      <%= link_to "hooter", root_path, id: "logo" %>
      <nav>
        <ul class="nav pull-right">
          <li><%= link_to "Home",    root_path %></li>
          <li><%= link_to "Help",    help_path %></li>
            <% if signed_in? %>
                <li><%= link_to "Users", users_path %></li>
                <li id="fat-menu" class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                        Account <b class="caret"></b>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><%= link_to "Profile", current_user %></li>
                        <li>
                            <%= link_to "Settings", edit_user_path(current_user) %>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                        <%= link_to "Sign out", signout_path, method: "delete" %>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            <% else %>
                <li><%= link_to "Sign in", signin_path %></li>
            <% end %>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

application.js

```
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all" %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= render 'layouts/shim' %>    
  </head>
  <body>
    <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
    <div class="container">
          <% flash.each do |key, value| %>
            <div class="alert alert-<%= key %>"><%= value %></div>
          <% end %>
          <%= yield %>
          <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
          <%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %>
        </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `jquery_ujs` is not picking up as per my guess

Comment: //= require jquery_ujs is present in application.js?

Comment: Do you have javascript disabled? You're sending gets for signout, instead of delete, which relies on javascript.

Comment: Otherwise, just delete your /public/assets folder, if you are convinced that it was the precompile that borked it.

Comment: @Amar the '//= require jquery_ujs' is present in application.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help from the commenters and outsiders I managed to fix the problem.

First of all I deleted the `public/assets` folder, which enable Heroku to do the compiling.

Then I moved `//= require bootstrap` below my `jquery` import as such:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue `No route matches [GET] "/signout"` is relevant because you effectively do not accept `GET` request on `/signout`, from your routes definition, it should be `DELETE` verb.

This may happen because of missing javascript library, could you check if some are missing ?

Comment: This helped me to understand the error, thanks. I just posted application.js to my question. In my app/assets/javascripts folder I have application.js, sessions.js.coffee, static_pages.js.coffee and users.js.coffee

Comment: It looks like all needed library are included in your `application.js`, now are they loaded in the HTML : do you have `<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>` code in your template in the `<head>` tag ?

Comment: It says `<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>` in my `<head>`tag, which I believe is what the tutorial recommended.

Comment: Are you seeing the HTML to require all library included in `application.js` in the HTML source of your page ? Can you access all of theses JS files from your browser ?

Comment: Im unsure how to test whether I can access the JS files in the browser? However, replacing `"application"` with `:defaults` didn't work. If you want to see the site, its on twitterforstudyspot.herokuapp.com

Comment: In your website, if you open the JS console you can see an error `jQuery is not defined` which means that there are problem for loading jquery library in your application. Maybe you can try to recompile your assets, just in case.

Comment: recompiling fixed the problem locally! However, after committing the changes and pushing to heroku, it still doesn't work on heroku?

Comment: Did you commit all the changes of compiled assets to Heroku ? If so, I suggest you to try on your local machine in `production mode` to reflect the Heroku setup.

Comment: I don't know if this is of any help, but the source-code on my local app shows around 14 different css and js files, whereas the heroku source-code only shows two (a css file and a js file. The js-file refers to `https://twitterforstudyspot.herokuapp.com/assets/application-838067296fb2c16544790ab7a22ab59e.js` which returns an error?

Answer (score 0):

Use this `application.js` file and try it

**application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

in your book that you are reading, see  `Listing 8.25.`

**Source** : http://ruby.railstutorial.org/book/ruby-on-rails-tutorial?version=3.2#sec-signin_upon_signup

Comment: I just added the application.js to my question. Everything seems to be there?